# How to understand on the consumer side that some messages were dropped within RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

There is a single consumer that receives all messages from a particular queue. The source of the messages is a single publisher. In my case it is a one-way communication and it is important to deliver all messages in order without losses. How can the consumer know that some messages have been dropped by RabbitMQ, for example, because the queue size limit has been reached?

I know that a message sequence number (defined by RabbitMQ) is used to confirm delivery to the consumer, so the question is: Is the sequence number a signal that messages have been dropped? For example, if the sequence number is not linear (difference between the received message and the previous message is greater than 1).

Comment: The example you mentioned (queue size limit) would not cause messages dropping, instead it won't allow new messages to be published (will return an error to the publisher), so the publisher should wait until the queue is ready to accept new messages.

Comment: @YairMaron, Sounds logical. I'll keep that in mind. Thank you.

But the question is whether I can use the built-in message sequence-number mechanism to control message loss on the consumer side.